# How to define ordered pairs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do we determine the ordered pairs in the relation determined by the Hasse diagram on the set A = {a, b, c, d, e}.

And how do we dreate the matrix representation of this poset.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hasse diagrams represent partially ordered sets.

In this case, the set is $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ (the vertices).

The order is characterized by edges between vertices. For example, $b$ has "children" $a$ and $c$, which means that $a<b$ and $c<b$ and there is no element $b^\prime$ such that $a<b^\prime<b$ and $c<b^\prime<b$. There's more on [the Wikipedia page about this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram).